# sshd can you open a session and be able to resume even when you disconnected

Tags: ssh

For example lets say I was in the middle of running a script I want to be able to keep the ssh session alive so I continue where I left off.

Comment: See `tmux` or `screen` commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **screen** (or **tmux**, but I'm not familiar with it) terminal multiplexer. First install it with `sudo apt install screen`. Then just start it with `screen`. You will get a normal terminal with a command line. You can start programs there as usual but you are able to detach from the screen terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. This will leave the screen terminal but a program that was started in screen is still running. If you want to reattach to the running program execute:

```
rpi ~$ screen -r
```

Within screen you can get help with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> or look at `man screen`.

Comment: May also be handy: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html I'd guess it's the stuff from `info screen` which is otherwise a little less user friendly than `man`.